# How can I copy a row of data automatically to another spreadsheet when a condition is met in a drop-down menu?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

Our small business uses a spreadsheet to track data from inquiries. Once booked, I need the data to automatically copy in the "Current Bookings" tab in the same sheet when "booked" is selected from a drop-down menu in the r.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet?

Answer (score 0):

- you can do something like this (change column reference to suit):

  ```
  =QUERY('Current Bookings'!A:Z; "where A='booked'"; 0)
  ```